# Set background checkbox android when dissable

Tags: android, checkbox

to day i work with it and I get a problem.
When I set Checkbox like:

```
checkboxsend.setEnabled(false);
```

Here i want the background of checkbox not change to disable?
What can i do that..please help me! Thank

The my xml:

```
 <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkboxsend"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="false"
    android:enabled="false" />
```

Comment: Mention your requirement clearly

Comment: Thank for read. I want the background of checkbox not change when i set checkbox.enable(false).

Comment: What do you mean by Background change?

Comment: android:enabled="true"

Comment: i want when i set enabled false, the checkbox not show like disable , checkbox show like normal ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use a state drawable as the background for the Checkbox, something like this should get you closer to your goal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@android:drawable/checkbox_on_background"/>
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@android:drawable/checkbox_on_background"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/checkbox_off_background"/>
</selector>
```

You can make modifications to this in order to match your exact logic.

Your CheckBox will look like this:

```
<CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
        android:checked="true"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this...If you don't want to change the background Color of your check box than....

Instead:

```
checkboxsend.setEnabled(false);
```

Use:

```
checkboxsend.setClickable(false);
```

Comment: what do you mean by not changing background of check-box...which background you talking about?